# Loop in R to extract data

Tags: r, loops

I have a very large data set and I'd like to extract from my files this sort of data:

```
start <- which(logger.dat$BA1>15 | logger.dat$KA1>15)[1] 
end <- tail(which(logger.dat$BA1>15 | logger.dat$KA1>15),1)

start
end

logger.dat$Time.ms[2]

logger.dat$Time.ms[988]

max(logger.dat$KA1[2:988], na.rm=TRUE)

min(logger.dat$KA1[2:988], na.rm=TRUE)

max(logger.dat$BA1[2:988], na.rm=TRUE)

min(logger.dat$BA1[2:988], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is this possible to do it with R?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: I have a data file with two columns, each represents two accelerometer readings. I have thousands individual files in one folder and want to find the first time at least one of the accelerometers reach 15g and the last time at least one of the accelerometers reach 15g. I want to create a loop to do this for all the files in one folder.